# Can't find the reason for my out of bounds exception

Tags: java, stringbuffer

So I need to write a method which allows me to find the next number without using anything but String and StringBuffer classes (so no parse or whatsoever).

when I run my code everything seems to work fine except for the last input (String k). It causes an outofbounds error in the while loop. But I don't see how It could do that because since my boolean should be false (I think because it only consists out of nine's) it shouldn't enter te loop in the first place.

```
public class Palindroom {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      String s="347"
            + "";           System.out.println("s "+increment(s));
       String p="199919";System.out.println(" p "+increment(p));
       String d="199999";System.out.println( " d "+increment(d));
       String k ="999999";System.out.println(" k "+increment(k));

}

static String increment (String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer (s);
    char laatst = sb.charAt(sb.length()-1);
    int laatste = sb.length()-1;

    if(laatst == '9') {
        int a = 1;
        boolean nine = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) != 9 ) {
                nine = true;

            } else nine = false;
        }
        if (nine == true) {
            while (sb.charAt(sb.length()- a) == '9'){

                sb.setCharAt(sb.length()- a, '0' );

                a++;
            }
            sb.setCharAt(sb.length()-a, ((char)((sb.charAt(sb.length()-a)+1))));

        } else if( nine == false) {
            System.out.println("negen "+nine);
            sb.insert(0, '1');
            for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
                if(sb.charAt(i)=='9') {
                    sb.setCharAt(i, '0');
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        sb.setCharAt(laatste,(char) (laatst+1) ); 
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: I don't know how the debugger works :(

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. It will let you solve problems like this and is a vital tool for serious software development.

Comment: Yeah, this is like saying "I have two pieces of wood and a long nail.  Can somebody attach them for me?  I don't know how a hammer works."  The debugger is pretty much THE most important tool for a programmer to learn to use.

Comment: ok thank you! I'll get to it immediately!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: based on the comments :) . Correct your logic for `true` and `false`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) == '9' ) {
                nine = true;

            } 
            else 
           {
               nine = false;
               break;
           }

        }
```

also you are getting an `out of bounds exception` because

```
while (sb.charAt(sb.length()- a) == '9'){

                sb.setCharAt(sb.length()- a, '0' );

                a++;
            }
```

after the fifth iteration `sb.length()- a` will be negative when the control comes to check the condition.

you are not getting the same error in other cases because the control never goes to the `while` loop (as `nine == false`)

OLD OBSERVATION

in

```
if(laatst == '9') {
        int a = 1;
        boolean nine = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            if (sb.charAt(i) != 9 ) {
                nine = true;

            } else nine = false;
        }
```

you are doing

```
if (sb.charAt(i) != 9 ) {
                nine = true;

            } else nine = false;
```

instead do, if you want to compare against the character 9,

```
if (sb.charAt(i) != '9' ) {
            nine = true;

        } else nine = false;
```

otherwise you are just comparing the ASCII value of the `charAt(i)` and so your `boolean` will only be `false`, if `charAt(i)` has ascii value 9

Comment: It doesnt matter.. At the end nine is going to be set to false for sure.. Reason : there is a 9 in sb..  else will have to execute everytime.. He is waiting for a 9 and then setting nine=9 ... Frankly the code makes no sense.. He might as well set nine=false right away...

Comment: This is a good observation, but it is not the reason for the error.  Upvoters, please explain yourselves!

Comment: OP has compensated for mixing up `9` and `'9'` by also mixing up `true` and `false` .... and you want him/her to write `if ( something != 9 ) { nine = true; }` ? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when your string consists only of 9s, your `while` loop causes `a` to exceed `sb.length()`.  Then, you end up trying to access the character at place -1 of `sb`.